# max integer value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm reading the [second chapter of the book Eloquent JavaScript](http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter2.html). The author states that:

> `Any whole number less than 2^52 (which is more than 10^15) will safely fit in a JavaScript number.`

I grabbed the value of 2^52 from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_of_two).

> `4,503,599,627,370,496`

The value has to be less than 2^52, so I've substracted 1 from the initial value;

```
var max = 4503599627370495;
```

After defining the max variable I'm checking what's the value (I'm using `Chrome 32.0.1700.77`).

```
console.log(max); // 4503599627370495
```

I'd like to see what happens when I go over this limit, so I'm adding one a couple of times.

Unexpectedly:

```
max += 1;
console.log(max); // 4503599627370496
max += 1;
console.log(max); // 4503599627370497
max += 1;
console.log(max); // 4503599627370498
```

I went over the limit and the calculations are still precise.

I tried the next power of two instead, 2^53, I didn't substract 1 this time:

> `9,007,199,254,740,992`

```
var max = 9007199254740992;
```

This one seems to be a bigger limit, it seems that I can quite safely add and substract numbers:

```
max += 1;
console.log(max); // 9007199254740992
max += 1;
console.log(max); // 9007199254740992
max -= 1;
console.log(max); // 9007199254740991
max += 1;
console.log(max); // 9007199254740992
max -= 900;
console.log(max); // 9007199254740092
max += 900;
console.log(max); // 9007199254740992
```

I can assign even a bigger value to the max, however it loses precision and I can't safely add or substract numbers again.

**Could you please explain precisely the mechanism that sits under the hood? An example of what happens with the bits after going above 2^52 would be really helpful.**

Comment: I don't thinks its a dupe, but just for reference: http://stackoverflow.com/q/307179/1169798

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is not a strongly typed programming language. JS has an object `Number`. You can even get an infinite number: `document.write(Math.exp(1000));`.

```
document.write(Number.MIN_VALUE + "<br>");
document.write(Number.MAX_VALUE + "<br>");

document.write(Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY + "<br>");
document.write(Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY + "<br>");

    alert([
         Number.MAX_VALUE/(1e293),
         Number.MAX_VALUE/(1e292),
         Number.MAX_VALUE/(1e291),
         Number.MAX_VALUE/(1e290),
    ].join('\n'))
```

Hope it's a useful answer. Thanks!

**UPDATE:**
max int is - +/- 9007199254740992

Answer (score 8):

You can find some information on JavaScript's Number type here: [ECMA-262 5th Edition: The Number Type](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_8.5).

As it mentions, numbers are represented as a 64-bit floating-point number, with 53 bits of mantissa (significant digits) and 11 bits for the exponent (IEEE 754). The result is then obtained with: mantissa * 2^exponent.

This means that up to 2^53 values can be represented in the mantissa (of those a few numbers have special meanings, and the others are positive and negative integers).

The number 2^53 (9007199254740992) can't be represented in the mantissa, and you have to use an exponent. As an example, you can represent 2^53 as `(9007199254740992 / 2) * 2^1`, ie. `mantissa = 9007199254740992 / 2 = 4503599627370496` and `exponent = 1`.

Let's check what happens with 2^53+1 (9007199254740993). Here we have to do the same, `mantissa = 9007199254740993 / 2 = 4503599627370496`. Oops, isn't this the same mantissa we had for 2^53? Looks like there's been some rounding error! :)

(Note: the above examples are not actually how it really works: the mantissa is always interpreted as having a dot after the first digit, which means that eg. the number 3 is actually stored as `1.5*2`. I omitted this in the above explanation to make it easier to follow.)

You can find some more information on floating-point numbers (in general) here: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Answer (score 3):

You can think of 52 bits integer in JS, but remember that bitwise logical operators `&` `|` `>>` etc.. will only deal with 32 less significant bits discarding the rest.